# I've got users logging with facebook but how do I get their data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I got users logging using this code:

```
  <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '[MY APP ID]',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('Logged in.');
      }
      else {
        FB.login();
      }
    });

      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
```

But how do I now access the users personal data such as their name, age, location, likes etc?

I've been looking at the guides on developers.facebook but I can't get it to work. What are the steps I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

For example, to get the basic data (which is mostly the name if you don´t ask for additional permissions):

```
FB.api(
    "/me",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Everything else you need to know is in the docs, starting from that reference page.

Side note - Your usage of `FB.login` is very bad, i suggest taking a look at this article and read it carefully: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: console.log(response) - just debug the response, it´s all in there